# how to sum elements of multiple lists in a loop?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples whose second element is a list:

```
[(1, [1]), (2, [1]), (3, [1]), (4, [1, 2]), (5, [1]), (6, [1, 2, 3]), (7, [1]), (8, [1, 2, 4]), (9, [1, 3]), (10, [1, 2, 5])]
```

I want to replace these lists with the result of their sum.

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 6), (5, 1), (6, 6), (7, 1), (8, 7), (9, 4), (10, 8)]
```

How can I achieve this?

I have no idea how to do this. I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
ml = [(1, [1]), (2, [1]), (3, [1]), (4, [1, 2]), (5, [1]), (6, [1, 2, 3]), (7, [1]),
      (8, [1, 2, 4]), (9, [1, 3]), (10, [1, 2, 5])]

s = 0
for el in ml:
    s += el[1]
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help!

Comment: "while removing the product of the sum " - what do you mean by "product of the sum"?

Comment: I need to sum the elements of each list inside the tuple and the sum should not be inside squared brackets Ex: (8, [1,2,4]) >> (8,7) instead of (8,[7])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
ml = [(1, [1]), (2, [1]), (3, [1]), (4, [1, 2]), (5, [1]), (6, [1, 2, 3]), (7, [1]), 
(8, [1, 2, 4]), (9, [1, 3]), (10, [1, 2, 5])]

ml_sum = [(a, sum(b)) for a, b in ml]

print(ml_sum)
```

outputs:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 1), (6, 6), (7, 1), (8, 7), (9, 4), (10, 8)]
```

If you have a list that contains tuples, you can loop trough multiple elements of those tuples at the same time!

Comment: I've tried this code, but got the error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-1ffed98c8c37> in <module>()
      2 
      3 
----> 4 ml_sum = [(a, sum(b)) for a, b in ml]
      5 

<ipython-input-45-1ffed98c8c37> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 
      3 
----> 4 ml_sum = [(a, sum(b)) for a, b in ml]
      5 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I edited my original answer to contain the complete code snippet. Does that work for you?

Comment: sounds like you've named a list `sum`